# MacGyver Angular mac-autocomplete directive not auto-completing

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I am including the .css and .js files for macgyver in my HTML.  I am also including 'Mac' as a dependency in my angular app.  I put this code in my HTML:

```
<mac-autocomplete ng-model="selected" mac-autocomplete-source="['hello', 'world']">
</mac-autocomplete>
```

And I get an input box, but it is not auto-completing.  Any ideas?

Comment: can you show your macAutocomplete directive? Also, can you show how you have included the directive dependency in the main file?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it doesn't look like you have any markup at all for the data autocomplete will generate. [From their website](http://starttheshift.github.io/MacGyver/0.3.4/#autocomplete), their markup for the data generated is just a simple `<span> {{item.label}} </span>` inside the tags you have. Second, it's `mac-autocomplete-url` rather than `mac-autocomplete-source` like you have (at least in the latest version of macgyver).

If those two things don't change anything, I'd suggest posting more about how you included the dependency. Check if the DOM is actually being updated too. Good luck!